# Quartz paths not drawing like I expect

Tags: objective-c, quartz-2d

I am trying to draw and fill simple paths in Quartz 2d for iPad.

The following method from the class SPTCutPattern defines the paths that I want to draw:

```
- (void) initDummyCutPattern {
NSArray *piece1Path = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 0)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 1)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 1)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 2)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 2)],
                       nil];
SPTPuzzlePiece *Piece1 = [[SPTPuzzlePiece alloc] initWithWidthInGrid:3 andHeightInGrid:2 andLeftInGrid:0 andTopInGrid:0 andBuilt:YES andPathInGrid:piece1Path];

NSArray *piece2Path = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 0)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5, 0)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5, 5)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4, 5)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4, 4)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 4)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 3)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 3)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 2)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 2)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 1)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 1)],
                       nil];
SPTPuzzlePiece *Piece2 = [[SPTPuzzlePiece alloc] initWithWidthInGrid:3 andHeightInGrid:5 andLeftInGrid:2 andTopInGrid:0 andBuilt:YES andPathInGrid:piece2Path];

NSArray *piece3Path = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 2)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 2)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 3)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 3)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 4)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4, 4)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4, 5)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 5)],
                       nil];

SPTPuzzlePiece *Piece3 = [[SPTPuzzlePiece alloc] initWithWidthInGrid:4 andHeightInGrid:3 andLeftInGrid:0 andTopInGrid:2 andBuilt:YES andPathInGrid:piece3Path];

self.pieces = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:Piece1, Piece2, Piece3, nil];
}
```

And this method from the class SPTPuzzlePieceView which is supposed to draw the paths:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
int widthUnit = self.frame.size.width / self.puzzlePiece.widthInGrid;
int heightUnit = self.frame.size.height / self.puzzlePiece.heightInGrid;
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, [[puzzlePiece.pathInGrid objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue].x*widthUnit, 
                     [[puzzlePiece.pathInGrid objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue].y*heightUnit);

for (NSValue *point in puzzlePiece.pathInGrid) {
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, [point CGPointValue].x*widthUnit, [point CGPointValue].y*heightUnit);
}

CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

I am getting these three objects, which are absolutely NOT what I expect and want:

[screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26067393/photo.PNG)

The objects are supposed to be more (or less) like this:

[shapes I wanted](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26067393/photo2.JPG)

I am sorry that these methods are totally taken out of context, so I hope you can see what I am trying to do.  The drawRect method gets called to draw each of the piece objects I defined in the first method in turn.

I cannot figure out why it is not drawing the shapes I want.  Help me please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second and third shapes are being initialised with `widthInGrid` and `heightInGrid` values smaller than their points.  This results in drawing outside the view bounds.

Three other things:

1. Consider using [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) for creating and drawing your path, instead of `CGContext...` calls.  It's harder to make mistakes with.  If at any point the user has to touch these shapes and drag them around, its `containsPoint:` method will be really handy.
2. The Objective-C naming convention for variables is that they start with lower-case, to distinguish them from class names.  So, you would have `SPTPuzzlePiece *piece1` instead of `*Piece1`.  Words within the variable name *do* use upper-case.
3. In `drawRect`, use the view's own `bounds` to get the width and height, not its `frame`.  These will be the same if you haven't distorted your view, but it's good practice to follow.  The `bounds` always define the coordinate space you're drawing into.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I understand perfectly what I was doing wrong now.  I will certainly look into those other suggestions too!